# Stop TableView backgroundView from going past last cell in each section?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, background, storyboard

I have a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController` nested in a `UITabBarController` that has multiple sections, each with a custom section header that is a subclass of a UIView. The `UItableView` has all the proper delegates and data sources set up in code and the storyboard.

The footer is explicitly set to 0 in code.

For whatever reason, it seems that the background (in red below) bleeds past each of the `UITableViewCell`s in each section.

My UITableView currently looks like this:

[image]

My settings for the tableview in the storyboard looks like this:

[image]

and finally, here is the code that controls the tableView, written as extensions on the UITableView subclass:

```
extension TestViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 64
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 34
}
}

extension TestViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


    let view = TestHeaderView()
    view.setLabelWithValues(valueType: "Example", amount: 1)
    return view
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestCell", for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell
    cell.testLabel?.text = "example"
    cell.testLabel2?.text = "example"
    cell.testLabel3?.text = "example"
    return cell
}
```

}

How do I prevent the background from going past each section of cells?

Comment: Looks like the space is due to Section footer. Try to implement `tableView(_:heightForFooterInSection:)` delegate method to reduce the height for footer.

Comment: @ntsh, Daniel Lyon good idea. Just tried it and the results are the same. Updated the question to include the code

Comment: Instead of `return 0` , try `return 0.001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

Looks like I had to set the footer size to 0 (which then defaults to 1) in the storyboard size inspector column like so:

[image]

This will leave a single pixel width of footer, so switch the background color to whatever your cell is.